# How to remove duplicate value and then calculate mean of each group using SQL?

Tags: sql

The data contains three column, name of person, group, and score.
Each person at least belongs to one group, may belongs to more groups. If a pearson belongs to more than one groups, the name will appear more than once, with different group but same score.
The problem is how to calculate the mean score of each group if each person is counted only for the first group he/she belongs to.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

A SQL table represents an *unordered* set.  There is no such thing as *the first group a person belongs to*, unless a column explicitly contains this information.

You can fetch an arbitrary row per person and then aggregate:

```
select groupid, avg(score) as score
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by groupid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by groupid;
```

This fetches the lowest group.  If you have another column, you can get the earliest or latest or whatever by changing the `order by`.